# React: Making own A/B testing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a way of displaying different components on a page at different weighted percentages (60% sees variant A and 40% sees variant B).
Is it feasible to do this on my own instead of getting a library?  I was thinking of handling it inside of `componentDidMount` and simply creating that will see what variant they will see, then create a cookie based on that and drive the render of the variant they will see from the cookie.
Does that make sense from an implementation point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would surely *make sense* as it is feasible to do it on your own, but then the question is why would you not use a library? For example, the [`@marvelapp/react-ab-test`](https://github.com/marvelapp/react-ab-test#weighting-variants) already has very good work undertaken by others, which includes [weighting variants](https://github.com/marvelapp/react-ab-test#weighting-variants) that is apparently one of your main requirements.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I believe it requires Webpack.  I am using Browserify/Gulp instead of webpack.